# Authentication for embedded client app on a device

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to create an IoT device that will store some of the collected data and configuration in firestore.

A user should be able access the data of his device from a mobile app.

I am concerned about the security on the device in case it would be reverse-engineered.

Theorically, a device should be able to only access and modify its data.
A user could possibly have access to mulitple devices.

I have seen multiple ways of doing authentication with Firebase :

- Firebase Admin, that is only for backend, so I can't use this.
- Firebase authentication, for client apps, to authenticate users.

I can't use the firebase authentication because the device could be used by multiple users, or even no user, but still updating its data to firestore.

What kind of authentication should I use for the client app on the device? 
I see multiple solutions :

- Create a user for each device that only has access to device's data and embed its credentials. This seems to be a heavy solution and the user datatabse will be harder to manage.
- Create an API key for each device to access firestore, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Will your IoT device only be reading data from firestore? Or does it needs to write data to firestore as well?

Comment: It needs to write data as well

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous authentication to authorize your IoT device access to firestore. Anonymous auth will not restrict your device with let say one email password authentication, so you can assign device to any user.

You will need to implement security features to restrict when an IoT device can read and write to firestore. This will help you cut off access to firestore if you think your device is compromised.

I'm assuming that each device will have some unique serial number to identify it. 
Create a data node where you map serial number to two Boolean a(read), b(write). When issuing a device/ or when a user from your app request to use that device, mark the boolean as true. This will identify that given serial number has read write access to it.

Now on data node where your device will write/read (e.g config/{serialNumber} or log/{serialNumber}), add firestore security rules which will check if the given serial number is authorize to read/write to it.

You can also divide iot write data in chunks based on which user is using it with scheme like log/{serialNumber}/{uid}

Comment: I'm afraid this answer might not because the anonymous authentication does not seem to be available from a python script. Am I correct?

Comment: are you using a library for python ?

Comment: You can always use rest api to create anonymous authentication. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-anonymously